# problem in running eclipse europa

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have been facing problems running Eclipse.
When i click it says "An error occurred. See log file .metadata.log"
following is what I see at the end of file

**Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config/server.xml' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:1949)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:1713)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
    ... 28 more**

I have installed tomcat server.
Using Windows Vista.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What are you clicking? Is Eclipse not starting or some operating within Eclipse fail. You should also consider moving to a newer version of Eclipse. Europa is ancient history now. Newer versions like Helios have not only been certified on Vista/Win7, but also have untold number of bug fixes.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520746

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have not specified the correct version of the Tomcat server you have installed, so Eclipse uses incorrect heuristics to configure Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration but problem was with uninstalled tomcat server and log file. I uninstalled tomcat. Eclipse was reading a log file and looking for the same. I now moved workspace. Newer log file created and now its working fine.

Comment: @Nitesh, please consider providing such information next time you ask a question.  The answers cannot be better than the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your best bet is to upgrade to a more recent version of Eclipse, such as Helios.

Comment: I needed it for temporary purpose. And I have found some problems with later versions. So will upgrade at a later stage, when more of bugs are removed.Europa is also working fine without tomcat. But with tomcat I faced sum problems while working with servlets.